# List transactions *relayed* by my full node?

Tags: bitcoind, connection, relay

Running Bitcoin Core full node 24/7, with 70+ peer connections. Is there a `bitcoin-cli` command that will let me see the transactions that my full node has *relayed* from its SPV "clients"?

FWIW, I can use Blockchain.info to search for my physical IP address. That should show all transactions with a matching "Relayed by IP" ... but the last transaction listed for my full node is 6+ weeks ago.

Trying to be a "good full node citizen," so I want to make sure everything is working AOK.

Answer (score 9):

Blockchain.info lists the first IP address it sees a new transaction from.

If you aren't the one creating the transaction, and aren't accidentally the node right in between the node that does and blockchain.info, it's unlikely that you're the first to do so. Furthermore, they may not even be connected to you the whole time.

To see what transactions are being relayed, start bitcoind with `-debug=net`, and look for 'inv' messages in the debug.log file.